# dnn loading available skins in custom module

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke, skins

I want to load all available skins in a dropdown list inside a custom module. What is the best way to do this?

VB code appreciated.

Thanks,
Amith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amith, the skins are typically located in Portals/XXX/Skins  where XXX could be _default, or a number or the name of a Portal.

I can't recall if all the skin paths are stored in the database. You may need to look at the database in SQL Server and take a look.

Otherwise just write some VB to look at the file system in that area, look for the Skins folder and any folder name within the skins folder is a skin package.  Any .ascx file within that folder is an available skin.

May help:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3681/list-files-in-a-directory/

http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/ListFiles.aspx

http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/visual-basic-how-list-files-directory-list-view-15722/